# Excepting Breaks In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, syntax-error, break

I know this sounds crazy, but I couldn't find a solution. I was trying to except the `break` statement inside a loop using `try-except`.
Here is what I tried:

```
for i in range(10):
    try:
        print(i)
        break
    except break:
        print("Break excepted")
        pass
```

But `Python3.x` returns the Error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So how do I except the `break` statement?
Ps: I know I could have the `print` statement before the `break` and avoid `break` statement, but if case I want to, how would I?

Comment: `break` isn't an exception. You can't catch it. Whatever you're trying to do, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: there is no way to stop break from action if it it used?

Comment: You put the break there. You can stop it by removing the break. You could throw an exception instead if you want to use `try/except`

Comment: does throwing exceptions break out of loops?

Comment: It will, if you don't catch it inside the loop.

Comment: In a way, exceptions are super-breaks. Whereas break just breaks out of the current loop, exceptions *can* break out of all loops and nested function calls right back out of the interpreter.

Comment: break is meant to be a surefire way of exiting a loop because there is no logical reason to continue with it. I think what you need to use is a `while` loop with a condition that you can set to false to break out of loop.

Comment: Ok. so should i delete and close the question, or wait for an answer and choose the naswer to close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a `break` exception because `break` is not an exception.

Also with the flow of operations, if the loop cannot run, your `print(i)` will not get executed and so the code will not reach the break statement anyways.

If you're trying to find at which loop the code breaks, your code should work without needing the break too.

```
for i in range(10):
    try #try running the loop
        print(i)
    except: #if the loop breaks
        print("Break excepted") #print this and continue loop
```

Because the `try` is inside the for-loop; when there is an exception, the loop will still continue with the next iteration.

You can of course, also catch more specific exceptions like `except IndexError` or `except KeyError`. [The full list of exceptions is available in the documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html)